# Undeclared JavaScript variable in functions overriding over uses

Tags: javascript, function, variables, scope, undeclared-identifier

I have two function examples as follows

```
function call1() {
    variable = "test string";
}

function call2() {
    variable = responseFromAJAX();

    document.title = variable;

    setTimeout(function() { call2(o); }, 1000 );
}
```

If there anyway that the undeclared variable "variable" can be overridden by either function? even when "variable" is not declared out the scope of the functions?

Many thanks

Comment: The `var` keyword is your friend.

Comment: Indeed. You should always use `var` to define variables and avoid global declarations because they can create really annoying 'little' bugs...

Comment: Here, many years later, it's the `let` and `const` keywords that are your friends (`var` should no longer be used in new code).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If there anyway that the undeclared variable "variable" can be overridden by either function?

Yes. Unless you're in strict mode, assigning to an undeclared variable creates a global variable implicitly (I call it [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html)). So either function can write to it. Fortunately, strict mode put a stop to implicit globals.

Comment: That link was an excellent article clearly explaining 'globals'.. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Yes if you are not declaring it as a type `var` it will be considered as a global variable.
It is the same as declaring a **global variable.**

So it will act as

```
    function call1() {
        variable = "test string";
    } // If you call this method variable will have the value as "test String"

function call2() {
    variable = responseFromAJAX();

    document.title = variable;

    setTimeout(function() { call2(o); }, 1000 );
} // If you call this method variable will have the value will be the value from AJAX
```